# Construction of rational between two reals

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading a book that uses this construction in a proof but I can't see why it works.

Suppose $s$ is real and positive, and $n$ is a positive integer. Then $w=\frac{[(n+1)s]}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}$ is a rational where $s<w<s+\frac{1}{n}$ and $[x]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to x.

I'm aware that such rationals exist, could someone explain why this is one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly $w$ is rational, as $[(n + 1)s]$ is an integer by definition of $[\cdot]$. The question then becomes to show that $s < w < s + \frac{1}{n}$.

Note that $[(n + 1)s] \le (n + 1)s$, as $[(n + 1)s]$ is an integer less than or equal to $(n + 1)s$. Moreover, it is the *greatest* such integer, so $[(n + 1)s] + 1$ is **not** less than or equal to $(n + 1)s$. That is,
$$[(n + 1)s] \le (n + 1)s < [(n + 1)s] + 1.$$
If we divide all three sides by the positive quantity $n + 1$, then we get
$$\frac{[(n + 1)s]}{n + 1} \le s < \frac{[(n + 1)s]}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 1} = w.$$
Recall also that $\frac{1}{n + 1} < \frac{1}{n}$, so
$$\frac{[(n + 1)s]}{n + 1} \le s \implies w - \frac{1}{n + 1} \le s \implies w - \frac{1}{n} < s.$$
Thus we get $s < w < s + \frac{1}{n}$ as required.